# Getting Error: $injector:unpr, Unknown Provider, myFilterFilterProvider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter, angularjs-factory

I'm new to angularjs and I'm having an issue setting up my module. I was able to use this module fine before with only a controller and filter. Since I added a `factory` directive I'm now getting the `Error $injector:unpr Unknown Provider` error, `Unknown provider: myFilterProvider` upon page load before calling anything. I tried following the steps in the docs and I can't figure it out. The filter worked fine before in the view and my controller doesn't use it but I added it to the dependencies. I only use the factory in the controller. Here is my setup:

```
angular.module('my-module', [])

.controller('my-app', function($scope, $http, $q, myFactory, myFilter) { ... }

.filter('myFilter', function() { ... }

.factory('myFactory', ['$http', '$scope', function(){
}]);
```

Top of view is:

```
<div ng-controller="my-app">
```

How do I inject the filter properly so I can overcome this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use filter in your controller, update your code from

```
.controller('my-app', function($scope, $http, $q, myFactory, myFilter) { ... }
```

to

```
.controller('my-app', function($scope, $http, $q, myFactory, $filter) {
     $filter('myFilter')
     ...
}
```

Additionally, if you have to pass any arguments to filter, you can update the code in controller to

```
$filter('myFilter')(argument 1);
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but I'm still getting the same error. Do I leave the filter as part of the module or do I define it in the controller?

Comment: Filter will be part of the module only. It should have worked. You can try an alternate also i.e. in place of $filter as argument, pass myFilterFilter as argument.

Comment: Still bugged fwiw my filter simply adds a zero to number with one digit. Idk if its something to do with it but here it is: `.filter('myFilter', function() {
 return function (input) {
  if(input < 10) {
   input = '0' + input;
  }
  return input;
 };
})`

Comment: Just make sure from that when you are calling filter you are passing integer values only. Additionally, you can try to update the condition from `input < 10` to `parseInt(input, 10) < 10`

Comment: That wasn't it either. What I don't get is that I don't call this filter until the page fetches results from a query. Why is it still giving an error? Could it be because the site is using minified angular?

Comment: Removing the factory and module declaration and changing it to app.controller{} .filter{} makes the code work again. Is the factory breaking the code? Is there a way to put the factory directly in the controller instead?

Comment: I reworked the factory into an object inside the controller and it works. Just have to make some tweaks so it can fetch results from cache.

Comment: Great things worked. Just for my information were you minifying above js as well?